# Django. Редирект на личную страницу

Tags: python

Использую LoginView для логина, мне нужно сделать так чтоб после успешного логина был редирект на личную страницу пользователя. Пользователей много, и в зависимости от пользователя должна быть выдана именно его личная страница.

lohin.url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
```

Пример параметизированного url личной страницы пользователя:

```
path('user/<str:username>/', user_page, name='user_page')
```

Как правильно это организовать? нужно как-то передать переменную с именем пользователя....

Answer (score 0):

Используйте редирект после успешного логина

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def method(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/user/{}'.format(request.user.username))
```